# squid cache server performance

Tags: ubuntu, networking, raspberry-pi, performance-testing, squid

I have one HP i7, 8GB, 1TB laptop and  two Raspberry Pi 3B+ single board computers with same OS(Rasbian). On my laptop I am using Ubuntu 18.04 and have installed/configured squid3 on it. This laptop and one of the Raspberry Pi board is connected to an access point wirelessly which is further connected to the Internet through Ethernet LAN. Another Raspberry Pi board is connected to the laptop through laptop Ethernet port and is accessing Internet through it(i.e. proxy server).
I wish to know which  Raspberry Pi board is having faster access to Internet.
What would be the best way to prove it? 
Thanx in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way would be just opening an Internet resources using a command-line tool like [wget](https://www.gnu.org/software/wget/) or [curl](https://curl.haxx.se/)

If you need more information like upload/download time and ping you can go for bandwidth measuring application like [speedtest.net](https://www.speedtest.net/) in the browser or if your Raspberry PIs don't have GUI you can go for a command-line script like [speedtest-cli](https://github.com/sivel/speedtest-cli)

If you need more "low level" information on the sockets performance you can go for [iperf](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iperf)

And finally if you need to perform some form of a load test by getting Internet resources in multiple threads - consider using a specialized [load testing tool](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/open-source-load-testing-tools-which-one-should-you-use/) like [Tsung](http://tsung.erlang-projects.org/)